# Setting kABPersonType

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I'm trying to set the kABPersonType value for a contact (ABAddressBook iOS).

```
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonType, [currentContact personType], nil);//person type (individual or company
```

[currentContact personType] is an NSNumber.

An error gets thrown when we reach ABAddressBookSave.

As follows;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6805ff0'
```

In all other cases; e.g.

ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty, [currentContact note], nil);

The setting of properties is fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Cheers,

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a record's record type. The record type is determined by the type of record you create (`ABPersonCreate()` or `ABGroupCreate()`) and cannot be changed later.

If you mean to set the person record *kind* (to person or company) instead, you have to use the correct constants: `kABPersonKindProperty` as the second argument, and the value argument (`NSNumber`) must contain `kABPersonKindPerson`.

Comment: That did it. I cant believe I was just using the wrong property. Cheers Ole.